# Did over 1000 people in the US die of cannabis overdose in 2021?

Tags: united-states, medical-science, recreational-drugs, marijuana

According to [the National Safety Council](https://injuryfacts.nsc.org/home-and-community/safety-topics/drugoverdoses/data-details/), in 2021 in the US, 1159 people died of cannabis overdose, of which 1130 of the deaths were preventable:

[image]

Is this true?

I'm skeptical because the drug enforcement agency says on its [Marijuana/Cannabis Factsheet](https://www.dea.gov/sites/default/files/2020-06/Marijuana-Cannabis-2020_0.pdf) "No deaths from overdose of marijuana have been reported".

Comment: I'm also very curious about the 29 *unpreventable* cannabis deaths due to overdose.

Comment: I did find this single example as to a THC-delivery device that can lead to overdose (cannabis contains THC), but it doesn't answer your question: https://www.newsweek.com/thc-overdose-death-marijuana-exposure-united-states-1442742

Comment: Also, the CDC page on overdoses has a section on marijuana, and while it mentions negative effects, it doesn't actually mention overdoses, despite that being the primary subject matter of the page: https://www.cdc.gov/drugoverdose/deaths/other-drugs.html#marijuana

Comment: Additionally, while this is a Canadian legal source, it does point to the possibility of there being some slight legal distinction between cannabis and marijuana, which indirectly relates back to the Newsweek story: https://www.legalline.ca/legal-answers/what-is-the-difference-between-cannabis-and-marihuana/

Comment: The chart says "select drugs".  I wonder why they chose to select cannabis and not nicotine and alcohol.  [Alcohol Poisoning Deaths — CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/vitalsigns/alcohol-poisoning-deaths/index.html) says that over 2000 people per year die of alcohol overdoses, and that's a direct cause, not simply contributing.

Comment: @RayButterworth Contributing would clearly shoot that number sky high. DUI incidents are non-trivial, and there are a lot more other types of contributing deaths and injuries.

Comment: Is cannabis listed also, even if the person dies of shotgun overdose?

Comment: I LOLed. The [Therapeutic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therapeutic_index) of morphine is 70. It's 15 for cocaine and ~10 for alcohol. As far as we know, it's ∞ for cannabis.

Comment: The lethal dose of THC is known - note, that is THC which is only a part of cannabis. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrocannabinol; I don't think anybody knows how much actual cannabis you have to somehow ingest to get to a lethal dose, but I somehow doubt it is realistic to think that it can be achieved naturally.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### That's not what this data says.

What's happening is that in cases of overdose deaths, both *causative* and *contributing* drugs get listed in this report. We have a hint in the description of the data, which states, "When comparing deaths by drug type, multiple drugs are often listed for one death." According to the data table, statistics are generated using ICD codes:

> Deaths are classified using the International Classification of Diseases, 10th Revision. Preventable drug poisoning deaths are identified using underlying cause-of-death codes X40-X44, while all drug poisoning deaths are identified by codes X40-X44, X60-X64, X85, and Y10-Y14.
>
> Among deaths with drug overdose as the underlying cause, the following multiple cause-of-death codes indicate the drug type(s) involved: Any opioid (T4NR-T40.4, T40.6), heroin (T40.1), methadone (T40.3), synthetic opioids other than methadone (including fentanyl, T40.4), natural and semisynthetic opioids (including oxycodone and hydrocodone, T40.2), benzodiazepines (T42.4), cocaine (T40.5), and cannabis (T40.7). Deaths involving more than one opioid category are counted in both categories.

Digging into the ICD codes a little deeper, however, we find this information, emphasis mine:

> Codes for **underlying cause** of overdose death include the letter X or Y
> (for example, X40: accidental poisoning, X60: intentional self-harm).
>
> Codes for opioid-related **contributing cause** of overdose death
> include a T (for example., T40.1: heroin, T40.4: other synthetic
> opioids).
>
> https://mnprc.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/using-icd-10-codes-to-assess-opioid-related-overdose-deaths.pdf

So, cannabis is only uniquely identifiable in this dataset under code T40.7, which merely indicates a "contributing cause" but not an "underlying cause" of death. I can't find any ICD code that denotes cannabis as an underlying cause of death - one might infer from the lack of such a code that fatal cannabis overdose is exceedingly rare.

Overall, it seems this data indicates that there were 1,130 people that died from a drug overdose who had marijuana listed as a contributing - but *not* principally causative - factor in the death. The data does not indicate that there were 1,130 deaths whose underlying cause was cannabis overdose.

It is possible that there are deaths caused by cannabis overdose which appear in other categories, but from this data there is no way to ascribe a number specifically to cannabis. It's theoretically possible that over 1000 fatal cannabis overdoses appear in other categories, but it seems medically unlikely. While we can't conclude from this data that there *aren't* over 1000 fatal cannabis overdoses, we also can't conclude from this data that there's even 1 fatal overdose caused by cannabis.

Comment: This says the T40 codes include "underdosing" https://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/S00-T88/T36-T50/T40-/T40.7 "Poisoning by, adverse effect of and underdosing of cannabis" If someone died from lack of cannabis, would that be included in the 1130?

Comment: @DavePhD That's not so ridiculous if you think about drugs which lead to strong physical dependence - during withdrawal, improper care could lead to death from complications of vomiting and diarrhoea, for instance. As far as I know, cannabis generally _doesn't_ cause physical dependence of that sort, so "lack of cannabis" is unlikely to be even a "contributing cause".

Comment: And it also doesn't distinguish between cannabis ONLY and cannabis "found in system". If someone died of a multi-drug OD, cannabis will end up part of the "contributing" even though someone ODing and die from it alone is almost unheard of.

Comment: Note that the non-existence of an ICD-Code meaning 'underlying cause of death is a cannabis overdose' implies that the WHO, who administers these codes currently believes  this is not even potentially a valid diagnosis. The list of existing ICD-Codes gets updated every year and if the WHO believed there could be cases where such a code would be appropriate, then it would exist.

Comment: @IMSoP cannabis has a strong sedation effect that certainly can be habit forming.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I specifically said "physical dependence *of that sort*" - i.e. the sort of dependence that produces potentially dangerous withdrawal symptoms such as vomiting and diarrhoea, so I'm not sure how "a sedation effect that can be habit forming" is relevant.

Comment: @IMSoP _"... death from complications of vomiting and diarrhoea ..."_ - Interestingly, there also exist more direct methods of death from drug withdrawal. For example, alcohol withdrawal can cause seizures, which can cause [permanent brain damage and even death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_withdrawal_syndrome#Progression).

Comment: @IMSoP as I recall cannabis does cause physical dependency.  That dependency is roughly the level of Caffeine, ie so minor as to be mostly safe to ignore; but still technically a dependency.

Comment: Its dependancy is on par with valium or xanax. Not safe to ignore at all.

Comment: @NeilMeyer that's utter nonsense.  Not even the same planet as those two.  Withdrawal from long term use of benzos requires significant medical intervention and careful tapering, possibly even the use of other medications.  Meanwhile Snoop Dogg could quit tomorrow and while it would be unpleasant, there would be no other medical issues.  Benzos are also vastly more addictive for most people, with physical dependency possible in literal weeks time

Comment: @Nelson Right... and the problem there is **cannabis is detectable months after use** - whereas hard drugs tend to be undetectable after a few days sober. So if they smoked a joint 3 months ago and die from an OD of something else, cannabis is going to pop up in the screen.

Comment: [X42](https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en#/X40-X49) includes cannabis in the category "narcotics and psychodysleptics [hallucinogens], not elsewhere classified"

Comment: [T40](https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en#/T36-T50) says "Excl. intoxication meaning inebriation ([F10-F19](https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en#/F12))" so it seems that the presumption is that cannabis *can* cause poisoning.  OTOH it doesn't seem appropriate to diagnose a corpse with "Mental and behavioural disorders due to use of cannabinoids(F12)" It is unclear how a diagnosing doctor would determine "poisoning" given detection of cannabinoids in the system, nor whether these codes are applied in a standardized way given what we know about how long cannabis remains detectable after use.

Answer (score 10):

If you "Download Table" from https://injuryfacts.nsc.org/home-and-community/safety-topics/drugoverdoses/data-details/ there's a bit more detail on where these data came from:

> Deaths are classified using the International Classification of Diseases, 10th Revision. Preventable drug poisoning deaths are identified using underlying cause-of-death codes X40-X44, while all drug poisoning deaths are identified by codes X40-X44, X60-X64, X85, and Y10-Y14.

X40-44 are all "accidental poisoning" causes, each number is a different category of drug. X60-64 are "intentional self-poisoning" equivalents. X85 is "assault by drug", Y10-Y14 are the "undetermined intent" equivalent of X40-44/X60-64. See https://mnprc.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/using-icd-10-codes-to-assess-opioid-related-overdose-deaths.pdf

**None of *these* codes identify cannabis specifically**. That is, while you could categorize a cannabis overdose under one of these codes, you would not be able to identify it as a cannabis overdose from the code. For example, X62 *includes* cannabis but also cocaine and heroin. The only way you'd specifically identify a *cannabis overdose* from these ICD codes is from the T40 range:

> Among deaths with drug overdose as the underlying cause, the following multiple cause-of-death codes indicate the drug type(s) involved: Any opioid (T4NR-T40.4, T40.6), heroin (T40.1), methadone (T40.3), synthetic opioids other than methadone (including fentanyl, T40.4), natural and semisynthetic opioids (including oxycodone and hydrocodone, T40.2), benzodiazepines (T42.4), cocaine (T40.5), and cannabis (T40.7). Deaths involving more than one opioid category are counted in both categories.

It seems likely that any time T40.7 is present, some other code is also present that indicates the "actual" cause of death.

Comment: Is the raw data available that would allow us to go from "likely" to "definitely" on your conclusion?

Comment: @IMSoP Possibly but I didn't see an explicit reference in the source to their source data. What **is** definitive is that it is not possible to ascribe a single cause using these codes.

Comment: I'm curious what subset of those numbers include (X62|X42|Y12)+T40.7... that might be as close as we can get to "cannabis *may have been* a significant factor in or potential underlying cause of death"

Comment: Possible Raw Data: https://wonder.cdc.gov/mcd.html

Comment: @DoktorJ The T-codes are not mutually exclusive, So one would have to look for some X/Y code for death by drug overdose + T40.7 + no other T4xxx code to get cases where cannabis is the most significant factor.

Comment: [X42](https://icd.who.int/browse10/2016/en#/X40-X49) includes cannabis in the category "narcotics and psychodysleptics [hallucinogens], not elsewhere classified"

Comment: @TimSparkles Includes but is not specific for, so there's no way to separate cannabis from, say, cocaine.

Comment: @BryanKrause My comment was addressed at "None of *these* codes mention cannabis specifically."  These codes do not specifically mention cannabis specifically *as the cause of death*, but they do specifically mention it as a member of the category of drugs which was the cause of death.  The remainder of that paragraph does I think sufficiently explain this, but the thesis is not quite correct in itself.

Comment: @TimSparkles I changed "mentions" to "identifies". I provide an example in the next sentence of what is meant by this. None of these codes are for cannabis specifically, so you cannot use them to identify cannabis overdose.